# Insect identification, Chennai, India

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Could someone tell me what the species of this beautiful insect is? Location: Chennai, India.
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To me, it looks like a Lepidoptera from the [Sphingidae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sphingidae) family (Hawk moths). It is similar to species in [Hemaris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemaris) and might belong to this genus.

One similar species from this genus (found in India) is [*Hemaris tityus*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemaris_tityus), but the moth in your picture doesn't look exactly like this particular species. Another similar species is [*Hemaris saundersii*](http://tpittaway.tripod.com/sphinx/h_sau.htm), which is found in and around India.

[image]

(*Hemaris tityus*, pic from wikipedia)

Comment: Thank you. I will try to find the exact species by going through Wikipedia. Thanks again!

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by @fileunderwater this moth belongs to the *Sphingidae*. It is *Cephonodes hylas* the **Coffee bee hawkmoth**, aka the **pellucid hawk moth** or **Coffee clearwing**. It is a largely distributed moth, found from the Middle east to Autralia.

Glass wings are not very common among butterflies. Research has shown that the glass wings of this species act like a sort of invisibility cloak, as explained in this [article](http://www.bioone.org/doi/abs/10.2108/zsj.14.737) and this [blog](http://www.australiangeographic.com.au/blogs/creatura-blog/2015/01/pellucid-hawk-moths-wings-like-invisibility-cloak)

[image]
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cephonodes_hylas